# Background selector declaration in CSS

Tags: css, selector, declaration

In CSS declaration for a selector is given as:

```
background-attachment: scroll; 
background-color: transparent; 
background-image: url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right top;
```

I want to optimize the code and change it to:

```
background: scroll transparent url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif) no-repeat right top;
```

My question is, Is this correct way and does it work in IE7/8, Firefox, Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct way and it works in all major browsers. You can read more about the CSS [`background`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background.asp) property which can be used to set all `background-*` properties together.

**Update:** Yes, the following rule will work:

```
background
{
    background: transparent url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif) no-repeat scroll 20px 40px;
}
```

Except the browser will attempt to apply this rule to an `<background>` element in the DOM. And since there's no such element in HTML, the rule will never be applied to anything. :-) So you have to change the rule selector to select the container element you want to apply the background property to:

```
div#myDivIWantToSetBackgroundTo
{
    background: transparent url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif) no-repeat scroll 20px 40px;
}
```

Btw, you can [play with various values for the background property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background) on the W3School site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question. If I want to give background-position as: 20px 40px; then the CSS rule should be something like this?
background
{
    background: transparent url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif) no-repeat scroll 20px 40px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. Take a look at point 6 here - http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-shorthands.php

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

> When using the shorthand property the
>   order of the property values are:
>
> ```
> * background-color
> * background-image
> * background-repeat
> * background-attachment
> * background-position
> ```

```
background
{
    background: transparent url(/images/ucc/green/btn-part2.gif) no-repeat scroll right top;
}
```